# Visual Studio 2013 Windows Form Application not running on Windows 8

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-8, windows-8.1

I've developed a **Windows Form Application .net 4.5** using **Visual Studio Ultimate 2013** under **Windows 8.1** for a client. But my client's laptop is using Windows 8, Intel Atom Processor and app is not running.

Installation steps has been executed successfully but when i click on the Application nothing is happening.

Is it not possible to target Windows 8 from Windows 8.1 Visual Studio Ultimate 2013?
If anybody has any idea what's wrong here, please tell me.
Thanks.

Comment: Check if .NET Framework 4.5 is installed on the laptop..

Comment: The application should work, probably you have some problems with dependencies, go to Event Viewer in Windows on the client computer and look for recent application startup errors, it may contain information about the startup problem

Comment: I checked **Turn Features on or off**  on his latop. .net 4.5 Advanced services was selected but ASP.NET 4.5 was not selected.

Comment: It's windows 8 to my knowledge Windows 8 includes .net 4 n 4.5 by default.

Comment: If it is a WinForms App, you don't need ASP.NET

Comment: @DenisYarkovoy What are you talking about?

Comment: Why wont it work? Everything seems fine.

Comment: @WhyCry He's talking about not selecting ASP.NET 4.5 Feature.

Comment: If your target cpu is 64bit check your compiler to be set on `Any CPU`

Comment: @WhyCry, yes, I am talking about not selecting ASP.NET 4.5 Feature.

Comment: @Siamak Yes it's set as Any Cpu. What if i'm targeting x86, do i need to change?

Comment: AnyCpu should work fine. Have you checked EventViewer in Windows control panel after you tried to start the application? It will give you more hints as to what's happening

Comment: Will only work if the exact same version of Net is on both computers.  The correct solution is to publish application and deploy using setup.exe folder which is created when publishing.  Publish using option "CD".  The move CD folder (containing setup.exe) to location where it can be executed by laptop.

Comment: @Dneis i'm not able to check my client's laptop as we're communicating via phone. I'll check it later.

Comment: @jdweng can u please elaborate ur comment. I made a installer using Visual Studio Installer Project.

Comment: I never use the installer.  Always publish.  Installing does 3 things 1) Adds any missing dlls and updates existing dlls if not the same 2) Update registry 3) create shortcuts

Comment: @jdweng by publishing did you mean Building Project in Release mode (\bin\release\)? if it's i'm trying and let me tell you if it's working.

Comment: From the build menu option Publish.  Will create in a new folder (specify in the build menus) a root folder containing setup.exe.  Then install like any purchase software package.

Comment: Guys, it was due to XML FileNotFoundException and solved it.